# Java SimpleDateFormat decrementing date by one day

Tags: java, date, simpledateformat

I am trying to reformat a date string using sdf. SDF is decrementing the date by a day. Pointers would be helpful.

java version "1.8.0_31"
Input:      ChangeDateStringFormat("10-Mar-2015");

Code:

```
public static String ChangeDateStringFormat (String Input) throws InterruptedException 
{           
    System.out.print("Input Date inside ChangeDateStringFormat : " + Input );

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-dd-yyyy");
    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("MST"));

    System.out.print(" || Output Date inside ChangeDateStringFormat : " +  sdf.format(new Date(Input)) + "\n");
    return sdf.format(new Date(Input));
}
```

Output Actual:

Input Date inside ChangeDateStringFormat : 10-Mar-2015 || Output Date inside ChangeDateStringFormat : Mar-09-2015

Output I was Expecting :

Input Date inside ChangeDateStringFormat : 10-Mar-2015 || Output Date inside ChangeDateStringFormat : Mar-10-2015

Comment: As an aside, *please* follow Java naming conventions. It really lowers cognitive dissonance.

Comment: Use java.util.Calendar to descrementing the date.

Comment: Since you use Java 8, use the new date/time API, please!

Comment: What happens if you take out `setTimeZone(...)`?

Comment: Do not use the deprecated `Date(String)` constructor to parse your input date.  Instead use a `DateFormat` that corresponds to your input.

Comment: You should set your formatter's `Locale` accordingly too, because Mar stands for March in English, Spanish and French, but not Germain (Mär), and quite an awful lot of languages without a Latin alphabet. That is, unless you know your argument will always be formatted according to the system's default Locale.

Comment: Since you are on Java 8 consider using the new [Date and Time-API](http://java.dzone.com/articles/introducing-new-date-and-time).

Comment: after commenting : sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("MST"));

I am getting the right output :

Input Date inside ChangeDateStringFormat : 10-Mar-2015 || Output Date inside ChangeDateStringFormat : Mar-10-2015

Just wondering if that would have ripple effect ?
Shouldn't format just change the formatting, and not perform any manipulation of data ?

Answer (score 4):

This is the problem:

```
new Date(Input)
```

You should *not* use that. Instead, construct a `SimpleDateFormat` to parse your input:

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
        System.out.println(convertDateFormat("10-Mar-2015"));
    }

    public static String convertDateFormat(String input) throws ParseException {
        TimeZone zone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("MST");
        SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy", Locale.US);
        inputFormat.setTimeZone(zone);
        SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM-dd-yyyy", Locale.US);
        outputFormat.setTimeZone(zone);

        Date date = inputFormat.parse(input);
        return outputFormat.format(date);
    }
}
```

However:

- If you're just parsing a date, you'd be better of specifying UTC as the time zone; you don't want to end up with problems due to time zones that switch DST at midnight
- If you're going to run this code on Java 8 and nothing lower, I'd strongly recommend using `java.time` instead of `Date`, `Calendar` etc.

Answer (score 0):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Test
        System.out.println(changeDateStringFormat("10-Mar-2015"));
    }

    static String changeDateStringFormat(String input) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtfInput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("d-MMM-u", Locale.ENGLISH);
        DateTimeFormatter dtfOutput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMM-dd-uuuu", Locale.ENGLISH);

        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(input, dtfInput);
        
        return date.format(dtfOutput);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Mar-10-2015
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/XyoE9R)

**Note:** [Never use SimpleDateFormat or DateTimeFormatter without a Locale](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65544056/10819573).

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

**Side Note:** Always follow [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html) e.g. the name of your function should be `changeDateStringFormat` instead of `ChangeDateStringFormat` and the parameter `Input` should be named as `input`.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>